# PHP RegExp Variable in Function

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a Function to parse UBBC and I want to use a function to find data from a database to replace text (a [user] kind of function). However the code is ignoring the RegExp Variable. Is there any way I can get it to recognise the RegExp variable?

PHP Function:

```
function parse_ubbc($string){
    $string = $string;
    $tags = array(
        "user" => "#\[user\](.*?)\[/user\]#is"
    );
    $html = array(
        "user" => user_to_display("$1", 0)
    );
    return preg_replace($tags, $html, $string);
}
```

My function uses the username of the user to get their display name, 0 denotes that it is the username being used and can be ignored for the sake of this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either rewrite your code to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback), as advised.

Or your rewrite the regex to use the `#e` flag:

```
function parse_ubbc($string){
    $string = $string;
    $tags = array(
        "user" => "#\[user\](.*?)\[/user\]#ise"
    );
    $html = array(
        "user" => 'user_to_display("$1", 0)'
    );
    return preg_replace($tags, $html, $string);
}
```

For that it's important that PHP does not execute the function in the replacement array immediately. That's why you have to put the function call into `'user_to_display("$1", 0)'` single quotes. So preg_replace executes it later with the `#e` flag.

A significant gotcha here is, that the username may never contain `"` double quotes which would allow the regex placeholder `$0` to break up the evaluated function call (cause havoc). Hencewhy you have to rewrite the regex itself to use `\w+` instead of `.*?`. Or again just use `preg_replace_callback` for safety.

Comment: This fits what I want as I have a lot of other code I removed for the sake of saving your time. Am just wondering if there's anywhere I could find out more about this?

Comment: There's just a few information in the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php about the `PREG_REPLACE_EVAL` modifier. Regarding the replacement code - it just has to be a valid expression. Enclosing function calls into single quotes often works best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) if you want to source replacements from a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse_ubbc($string){
    $string = $string;
    function get_user_to_display($m){
        user_to_display($m[1], 0);
    }
    return preg_replace_callback('#\[user\](.*?)\[/user\]#is', 'get_user_to_display', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `user_to_display()` with the string '$1', not the actual found string. Try:

```
function parse_ubbc($string){
    $string = $string;
    $tags = array(
        "user" => "#\[user\](.*?)\[/user\]#ise"
    );
    $html = array(
        "user" => 'user_to_display("$1", 0)'
    );
    return preg_replace($tags, $html, $string);
}
```

The changes are adding 'e' to the end of the regexp string, and putting the function call in quotes.